# Output XSLT <xsl:message> without trailing line break

Tags: xml, xslt, rspec

I am using `<xsl:message terminate="yes">` to output an error when processing my XML file. That works fine, but when I try to expect that error in RSpec I run into the fact that it is apparently adding a line break to the end of the xsl:message. I don't want to add a weird line break to my test, I'd prefer to remove the line break from the xsl:message.

XML:

```
<prog Id="fooid"></prog>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="prog">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="second-pass"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="prog" mode="second-pass">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes"><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/> was dropped</xsl:message></xsl:template>
```

In my test code:

```
it 'raises an error when an item matches no other templates' do
  expect{item_from_xml('<prog Id="fooid">')}.to raise_error(RuntimeError.new('fooid was dropped'))
end
```

but the output is:

```
Failure/Error: expect{item_from_xml('<prog Id="fooid">')}.to raise_error(RuntimeError.new('fooid was dropped'))
       expected #<RuntimeError: fooid was dropped>, got #<RuntimeError: fooid was dropped
       > with backtrace:
```

You can see the additional line break at the end.

The code for item_from_xml is below:

```
  def item_from_xml(xml, params=['country', "'US'"])
    xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read(XSL FILE HERE))
    xslt.transform(Nokogiri::XML(xml), params)
  end
```

I tried to normalize-space in the `<value-of select` field but that didn't do much as it only effected the @Id. I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="prog" mode="second-pass">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(@Id, ' ', 'was dropped'))"/></xsl:message></xsl:template>
```

but that led to the exact same output. I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="prog" mode="second-pass">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes"><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/><xsl:text> was dropped</xsl:text></xsl:message></xsl:template>
```

again with no luck. I don't want to remove trailing new lines from the entire file, only in this condition where I am using a terminating message. I feel like there is probably something silly I am missing but I'm fairly new to XSLT and I can't seem to get this one.

Comment: Formatting of the output of xsl:message is entirely implementation-defined, and most processors don't give you much control over it.

Comment: As Michael Kay notes, `xsl:message` output is entirely dependent on each processor's implementation.  From "the W3C specification":https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#message: _"The xsl:message instruction sends a message in a way that is dependent on the XSLT processor."_  Since your particular XML processor adds a newline, you're probably much better off simply adding a newline on the end of the string in your test code.